duda api paypal: porque la fecha en next_billing_time y final_payment_time es igual a la fecha de creacion de subscripcion paypal?
Hola tengo una duda que no logro resolver o entender del todo bien. Estoy practicando con la api de PAYPAL entonces eh creado un metodo de pago para trabajar con subscripciones y pagos recurrentes.
Despues de realizar el pago se registra mi pago entonces al momento de consultarlo obtengo esto:
{
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "status_update_time": "2024-07-30T23:41:23Z",
    "id": "I-WKTEABWKULAC",
    "plan_id": "P-12961327HY283731FM2UXT7Y",
    "start_time": "2024-07-31T23:40:45Z",
    "quantity": "1",
    "shipping_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "0.0"
    },
    "subscriber": {
        "email_address": "sb-09nnp31069604@personal.example.com",
        "payer_id": "37BARHK2BP524",
        "name": {
            "given_name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe"
        },
        "shipping_address": {
            "address": {
                "address_line_1": "Free Trade Zone",
                "admin_area_2": "Quito",
                "admin_area_1": "Quito",
                "postal_code": "170203",
                "country_code": "EC"
            }
        }
    },
    "billing_info": {
        "outstanding_balance": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "0.0"
        },
        "cycle_executions": [
            {
                "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
                "sequence": 1,
                "cycles_completed": 0,
                "cycles_remaining": 1,
                "current_pricing_scheme_version": 1,
                "total_cycles": 1
            }
        ],
        "last_payment": {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "11.0"
            },
            "time": "2024-07-30T23:41:22Z"
        },
        "next_billing_time": "2024-07-31T10:00:00Z",
        "final_payment_time": "2024-07-31T10:00:00Z",
        "failed_payments_count": 0
    },
    "create_time": "2024-07-30T23:41:21Z",
    "update_time": "2024-07-30T23:41:23Z",
    "plan_overridden": false,
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-WKTEABWKULAC/cancel",
            "rel": "cancel",
            "method": "POST"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-WKTEABWKULAC",
            "rel": "edit",
            "method": "PATCH"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-WKTEABWKULAC",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-WKTEABWKULAC/suspend",
            "rel": "suspend",
            "method": "POST"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-WKTEABWKULAC/capture",
            "rel": "capture",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}

si se ve bien en las fechas para pagos siguientes tengo
       "next_billing_time": "2024-07-31T10:00:00Z",
        "final_payment_time": "2024-07-31T10:00:00Z"

Pero si se supone que se pago por un plan recurrente mensual estos valores ¿no deberian tener fecha para el próximo mes? Pero en vez de ocurrir eso supuestamente el proximo cobro se hara el dia siguiente cuando se supone que es un plan mensual.
Ahora desde laravel eh enviado este request
 $billingPlanData = [
                'product_id' => 'PROD-7WG52586HG985143T', 
                'name' => 'Premium plan',
                'description' => 'Premium plan',
                'status' => 'ACTIVE',
                'billing_cycles' => [
                   
                    [
                        'frequency' => [
                            'interval_unit' => 'MONTH', 
                            'interval_count' => intval($month) //$month puede tener valores del 1 al 12 segun la duracion
                        ],
                        'tenure_type' => 'REGULAR',
                        'sequence' => 1,
                        'total_cycles' => intval($month),
                        'pricing_scheme' => [
                            'fixed_price' => [
                                'value' => $total,
                                'currency_code' => 'USD',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'payment_preferences' => [
                    'auto_bill_outstanding' => true,
                    'setup_fee' => [
                        'value' => '10',
                        'currency_code' => 'USD',
                    ],
                    'setup_fee_failure_action' => 'CONTINUE',
                    'payment_failure_threshold' => 3,
                ],
                'taxes' => [
                    'percentage' => '10',
                    'inclusive' => false,
                ],
            ];

NO se si ese sea el problema. Eh buscado por todos lados y no entiendo si la respuesta obtenida es correcta o yo estoy haciéndolo mal. No se que podría estar mal.
